# How do i load a specific column of information from a table into an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

So, i'm supposed to load information from the SORCE database using a url with variables for the begin and end date of information and then create an array for the wavelength.

i'm saving the data using:

```
   url = "http://lasp.colorado.edu/lisird/tss/sorce_ssi.csv?&time>=%(YYYY)04d-%(MM)02d-%(DD)02d&time<%(yyyy)04d-%(mm)02d-%(dd)02d" %{"YYYY":YYYY, "MM":MM, "DD":DD, "yyyy":yyyy, "mm":mm, "dd":dd}
urlptr = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = ascii.read(urlptr)
```

this gets an output like:

```
time (days since 2003-01-24) wavelength (nm) ... instrument (id) version
---------------------------- --------------- ... --------------- -------
                      2534.5             0.5 ...            57.0    10.0
                      2534.5             1.5 ...            57.0    10.0
                      2534.5             2.5 ...            57.0    10.0
                      2534.5             3.5 ...            57.0    10.0
                      2534.5             4.5 ...            57.0    10.0
                      2534.5             5.5 ...            57.0    10.0
                      2534.5             6.5 ...            57.0    10.0
                      2534.5             7.5 ...            57.0    10.0
                      2534.5             8.5 ...            57.0    10.0
                      2534.5             9.5 ...            57.0    10.0
                      2534.5            10.5 ...            57.0    10.0
                         ...             ... ...             ...     ...
                      2898.5         2300.43 ...             nan     nan
                      2898.5         2311.89 ...             nan     nan
                      2898.5         2323.28 ...             nan     nan
                      2898.5         2334.63 ...             nan     nan
                      2898.5          2345.9 ...             nan     nan
                      2898.5         2357.11 ...             nan     nan
                      2898.5         2368.28 ...             nan     nan
                      2898.5         2379.37 ...             nan     nan
                      2898.5         2390.42 ...             nan     nan
                      2898.5          2401.4 ...             nan     nan
                      2898.5         2412.34 ...             nan     nan
```

and my first thought to create the wavelength array was to write something like:

```
wlength = loadtxt(data, usecols=(1))
```

However, when i run this i get a type error saying that the 'int' object isn't iterable.

I know that ints aren't iterable, but how do i make the information i'm looking for into something that is iterable?

Comment: So from the URL it looks like this is just a CSV? Why not just use the csv package built-in to python? https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: I did not know of its existence

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using the csv module:

```
import csv
import urllib2

wavelengths = []
# small time range for example
url = "http://lasp.colorado.edu/lisird/tss/sorce_ssi.csv?&time%3E=2014-01-01&time%3C2014-01-10"
urlptr = urllib2.urlopen(url)

csv_reader = csv.reader(urlptr)
first_line = True
for row in csv_reader:
    if first_line:
        first_line = False
        continue
    wavelengths.append(row[1])

print "There's", len(wavelengths), "wavelengths"
print "First 10", wavelengths[:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `pandas` library. This will be fairly easy to do.

```
import pandas as pd

YYYY = 2003
MM = 1
DD = 24

yyyy = 2003
mm = 3
dd = 1

url = "http://lasp.colorado.edu/lisird/tss/sorce_ssi.csv?&time>={0}-{1:02}-{2:02}&time<{3}-{4:02}-{5:02}".format(YYYY,MM,DD,yyyy,mm,dd)

df = pd.read_csv(url)
print df.head() # Prints the first 5 lines as a preview.

# Create array of wavelength.
wavelength_col = df["wavelength (nm)"]

# Print the maximum value of the column.
print wavelength_col.max() #2412.34
```

You can see installation instruction for `pandas` as well as check out the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/).